# Void function in c

Tags: c

What does actually mean when the function is defined by a type defined in struct. To understand me better here is an example:

```
typedef struct node { 
int number;
struct node *left, *right; 
} Node;

typedef Node *tree;

tree makenew (void) { return NULL; }
```

What is different in this function (makenew) that is defined by tree from function defined with int or void, does this mean that the function must return a value that is tree?

Comment: @EdHeal: If you're suggesting `tree makenew()`, that's a non-prototype declaration; it's an obsolescent feature retained for compatibility with pre-ANSI C, and it doesn't let the compiler check whether callers correctly pass no arguments. `tree makenew(void)` is preferred. (Perhaps you're thinking of C++, which has different rules.)

Comment: guys, what is actually meaning of (void) here?

Comment: @KeithThompson - Just a comment that it is no longer required. But you can bung it in. That why I put it as a comment

Comment: In a function declaration or definition, `(void)` means that the function takes no arguments. `()` would be more consistent, but that already had a meaning in very old versions of C, so the `(void)` syntax was invented.) @EdHeal: Your comment seems to encourage using `()` rather than `(void)`; that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
int foo(void) { return 1; } // returns an int

void foo(void) { return; } // returns nothing

tree foo(void) { return NULL; } // returns a "Node *" which is typedef'ed to tree
                                // the value of the pointer is NULL
```